# Put lottie animation in background

Tags: html, css, svelte, lottie

I can't figure out how I can use a Lottie animation in the background and put text over it.

I am using Svelte in case it matters.

```html
<section>

  <div class="animation">

    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
    <lottie-player src="static\animation.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>

    <h1>
      Title
    </h1>

    <h2>
      Text
    </h2>
  </div>
</section>

<style>
  section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
  }
  
  h1 {
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }
</style>
```

I tried using z-index but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Looks like you are missing some code in this question, the structure is wrong, no open section element and h1 is not closed, the issue might be because of that try to create a sandbox page using https://codesandbox.io/s/ or something else so that answer can be given appropriately. anyways, I have made this work here https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-butterfly-c2y8o

Comment: I have put it here https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-mendel-fi2wq

Comment: Awesome, updated code here : https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-butterfly-c2y8o
hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know you mean this, but hope it could help you.

```css
section {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex: 1;
    position: relative;
}

.title {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <div class="animation">
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/@lottiefiles/lottie-player@latest/dist/lottie-player.js"></script>
        <lottie-player src="static\animation.json" background="transparent" speed="1" style="width: 1000px; height: 1000px;" loop autoplay></lottie-player>

    </div>
    <div class="title">
        <h1>Title</h1>
        <h2>Text</h2>
    </div>
</section>
```